# Can a number field have an irreducible polynomial of any degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

We all know that all the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are linear and in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ they aren't over  2 degree.However,in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ we can have an irreducible polynomial in any degree.

So the question is: for any given $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ does there exist a number field $P(\mathbb{Q}\subseteq P\subseteq\mathbb{C})$ such that all the irreducible polynomials in $P[x]$ aren't over $n$ degree ,and there does exist an irreducible polynomial of $n$ degree?

Comment: No matter what number field $K$ you pick, there is an irreducible (watch your spelling: not "incredible") polynomial of each degree $n$ in $K[x]$:  let $\mathfrak p$ be a nonzero prime ideal in $\mathcal O_K$ and use $x^n - a$ where $a \in \mathfrak p - \mathfrak p^2$.  This polynomial is irreducible in $K[x]$ by a version of the Eisenstein irreducibility criterion.

Comment: @KCd. But in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ all irreducible polynomials are linear.(Sorry for my spelling)

Comment: Closely related [Over which fields do there exist irreducible polynomials of every degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3068942/242)

Comment: I am not writing about irreducibles over the complex numbers, but only over $K$.  The polynomial $x^3 - 2$ is irreducible in $\mathbf Q[x]$ but not in $\mathbf R[x]$ too, and $\mathbf Q \subset \mathbf R$.  It's the same idea.

Comment: @BillDubuque It seems  not to give a certain answer...

Comment: Number field is finite extension by definition right? So if it isn't true for rationals it cannot be true for a finite extension of rationals.